# Change the side of the axes

Tags: graphics

How can I change the side of the y-axes. Just change to the left side like usual and not to the right side as seem is in the figure.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Include the code (in a code block not in an image) used to generate the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way might be

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> {{False, True}, {True, False}}, 
 Axes -> False,FrameTicks->{{Automatic,All},{All,Automatic}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 m = Transpose[{-#, #}] &[Range@10];

Grid[{{
   ListPlot[m],
   ListPlot[m, AxesOrigin -> {-10, 0}, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
   }}]
```

[image]